# Routing issues with lazy loading

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm pretty new with angular2 and i'm currently facing some weird issues with routing especially with lazy loading.

My app is separated in two ( more coming ) layouts, for this purpose i'm using two components ( PublicComponent and SecureComponent ) this allow me to load totally different layouts and also organise the project to be scalable.

With my routing setup i have two issues :

1. root page ( like : http://myapp.com ) is loading the CustomerListComponent instead of the HomeComponent and this is also bypassing the SecureComponent
2. customer/edit/:id has a very strange behavior its loading the right template but the url load is /customer and the component code is generating error because id parameter is obviously not provide

My app-routing.module.ts :

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {
        path: '',
        component: PublicComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        component: SecureComponent,
        canActivate: [LoggedInGuard],
        children: [
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'customer',  loadChildren: 'app/customer/customer.module#CustomerModule' }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

customer-routing.module.ts :

```
export const CUSTOMER_ROUTES : Routes = [
  { path: '', component: CustomerListComponent },
  { path:'new', component: CustomerEditComponent },
  { path:'edit/:id', component: CustomerEditComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(CUSTOMER_ROUTES)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Do you have any ideas of what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: What will be if you change route to HomeComponent?

Comment: no changes with this

Comment: Remove `CustomerListComponent` and see what changes will be.

Comment: In that case http://myapp.com is redirecting to /home correctly which is the expected behavior.
 it seems that the parent path is not taken in account here :s

Comment: Define which path is parent and why.

Comment: In addition strange things are "working" :
- /new is pointing to CustomerEditComponent without loading SecureComponent which is not supposed to happen as the route is supposed to customer/new which is working great here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129742/discussion-between-fabien-meynard-and-roman-c).

Comment: customer is the parent path as its loading the SecureComponent layout

Comment: Then move it to the parent path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out.
My mistake was in lazy routes configures i have to specify the path too.

here my working setup :

app-routing.module.ts

```
const APP_ROUTES : Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
        path: '',
        component: PublicComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        canActivate: [LoggedInGuard],
        component: SecureComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            {
                path: 'customer',
                loadChildren: 'app/customer/customer.module#CustomerModule'
            }
        ]
    }
];



@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

And my customer-routing.module.ts

```
export const CUSTOMER_ROUTES : Routes = [{
  path: 'customer',

  canActivate: [ LoggedInGuard ],
  component: SecureComponent,
  children: [
        { path: '', component: CustomerListComponent },
        { path:'new', component: CustomerEditComponent },
        { path:'edit/:id', component: CustomerEditComponent }
  ]
}];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(CUSTOMER_ROUTES)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Thanks a lot Roman C for his help.

Answer (score 0):

well you have added multiple Path with  `path:''`  which is wrong. imagine if your website is www.localhost.com for this path you have assigned it to publicComponent and SecureComponent.

your app-routing.module.ts should be like something this..

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'loginmain', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {
        path: 'loginmain',
        component: PublicComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'secure',
        component: SecureComponent,
        canActivate: [LoggedInGuard],
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo:'home'},
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'customer',  loadChildren: 'app/customer/customer.module#CustomerModule' }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Comment: Exactly same behavior :(